# BarChart Labels in primefaces not showing

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

I am working at a project that requires a BarChart at the index page.

I want it to display underneath the bars, the labels set in the chart series, but it only will display the value set in the first chart series added to the chart model.

Here is my code:

```
    vencidoMas90dias = new BarChartSeries();
    vencido90dias = new BarChartSeries();
    vencido60dias = new BarChartSeries();
    vencido30dias = new BarChartSeries();
    vence30dias = new BarChartSeries();
    vence60dias = new BarChartSeries();
    vence90dias = new BarChartSeries();
    vencidoMas90dias.set(">90 días", v.getVencidoMasTresMeses());
    vencido90dias.set("90 y 60 días", v.getVencidoTresMeses());
    vencido60dias.set("60 y 30 días", v.getVencidoDosMeses());
    vencido30dias.set("30 y 1 día", v.getVencidoMes());
    vence30dias.set("1 a 30 días", v.getTreintaDias());
    vence60dias.set("30 a 60 días", v.getSesentaDias());
    vence90dias.set("60 a 90 días", v.getNoventaDias());

    modelo.addSeries(vencidoMas90dias);
    modelo.addSeries(vencido90dias);
    modelo.addSeries(vencido60dias);
    modelo.addSeries(vencido30dias);
    modelo.addSeries(vence30dias);
    modelo.addSeries(vence60dias);
    modelo.addSeries(vence90dias);
```

But the chart is displaying only one label in the center bar, and I need to display the label for each bar.

Does anybody know what is wrong with this? I am using Primefaces 4.0, and the examples in the showcase seem to have some differences, and they are not very clear sometimes.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to draw BarChart, why add BarChartSeries? I think you could setup BarChart with the following code:

```
CartesianChart modelo = new CartesianChart();

modelo.setLabel("Label");

ChartSeries s = ChartSeries();

s.set(">90 días", v.getVencidoMasTresMeses());
s.set("90 y 60 días", v.getVencidoTresMeses());
s.set("60 y 30 días", v.getVencidoDosMeses());
s.set("30 y 1 día", v.getVencidoMes());
s.set("1 a 30 días", v.getTreintaDias());
s.set("30 a 60 días", v.getSesentaDias());
s.set("60 a 90 días", v.getNoventaDias());

modelo.add(s);
modelo.setTitle("Title");
```

Comment: Thank you @Marius for your answer. What you suggest is working fine, but I need to identify each bar with different colors, that is the reason I make different ChartSeries.

Still, I appreciate your soon answer to my issue. Do you know if the colors of the same series can be different?

Comment: To have different colors, use setSeriesColors with a comma separated list of colors. Like this modelo.setSeriesColors("66cc66,93b75f,E7E658,cc6666"); :)

Comment: Sorry @Marius, but there is not a method called setSeriesColors in the model or the series :\

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention this in previous comment. Now edited the answer. Somehow "BarChart is created with an org.primefaces.model.chart.CartesianChartModel instance." [see PrimeFaces User’s Guide p. 72](http://primefaces.googlecode.com/files/primefaces_users_guide_4_0_edtn2.pdf) . I think it has a method [setSeriesColors](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/4.0/org/primefaces/component/chart/UIChart.html#setSeriesColors(java.lang.String)) in [CartesianChart](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/4.0/org/primefaces/component/chart/CartesianChart.html).